# jquery background image css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try all time this works and i can´t get i put the code :

**CASE 1 CODE NO WORKS**

```
onmouseover="jQuery(this).css({background-image:url('<?php echo $ur;?>')});"
```

I think the code it´s ok but no get works , the url it´s ok , only work me if use this :

**CASE 2 CODE WORKING OK**

```
onmouseover="jQuery(this).css('background-image','url('<?php echo $ur;?>')');"
```

But in the first case no works , i need use the first case because i need add some code more of css

I don´t understand what happend for no works

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: The first one is a syntax error, you can't have hyphens outside strings like that, then it's really a minus sign. You can use either camelcase, and do `backgroundImage`, which is what you'd generally do in javascript, or you can quote it so it's a string, which jQuery will understand.

Comment: I think the value should be in quotes for case 1: `background-image: "url('...')"`

Comment: Thank´s for the help , i don´t understand the negatives , negatives for my question , i don´t understand , don´t understand this community

Answer (score 2):

You can multiple lines of css by calling the function multiple times:

```
<script>
function myMouseOver() {
  jQuery(this).css('background-image','url('<?php echo $ur;?>')');
  jQuery(this).css('margin','1337');
  jQuery(this).css('padding','1337');
  // etc
}
</script>
```

And then wherever you use the mouseover,

```
onmouseover="myMouseOver()"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind in your html.  Separate your markup from your logic as much as possible.

```
<tag class="something" data-background="<?php echo $ur;?>"></tag>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$('.something').on('mouseover', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('backgroundImage', "url('"+ $this.data('background') +"')");
}).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundImage', '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> CSS properties that normally include a hyphen need to be camelCased in
>   JavaScript.
>   For example, the CSS property `font-size` is expressed
>   as `fontSize` when used as a property name in JavaScript.
>
> However,
>   this does not apply when passing the name of a CSS property to the
>   `.css()` method **as a string** – in that case, either the camelCased
>   or hyphenated form will work.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/css-styling-dimensions/

always use camelCase when CSS is used as object properties

```
onmouseover="jQuery(this).css({backgroundImage:url('<?php echo $ur;?>')});"
```

And you're using jQuery, so why not use a proper event handler as well

```
$('.element').on('mouseeover', function() {
    $(this).css({
        backgroundImage : 'url(' + $(this).data('bg') + ')'
    });
});
```

and then

```
<div class="element" data-bg="<?php echo $ur;?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to change a background image CSS with jQuery.

```
jQuery(this).css('background-image','url('<?php echo $ur;?>')');

jQuery(this).css({'background-image':'url('<?php echo $ur;?>')'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with .attr function to change style attribute:

```
onmouseover="jQuery(this).attr('style', 'background-image:url(<?php echo "'"+$ur+"'";?>)');"
```